# Why is my main process continuing to run when using pool.starmap() despite calling .close() and .join()?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to get my main process to wait for my pool of workers to finish. and then carry on, and do other stuff with the output. Input here is a function "download", and a list of tuples "dataList". I would have expected pool.close(), and pool.join() to accomplish what I wanted, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(3)
    filePaths = pool.starmap(download, dataList)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


print(filePaths)

#output: nameError, filepaths not defined
```

Comment: I think you should put the print-statement inside the if-statement.

Comment: I hear that, and that works to make the code work, but what I want to actually do is carry on and do something with filePaths other than print.

Comment: Yeah, all of that other work should also go inside the if-statement. When there is a code outside of if-statement, it can possibly be run inside the child processes (child processes made by the pool) where filePaths is not defined (or calculated) yet. So any use of filePaths should go inside the if-statement to make sure no child process accidentally runs that piece of code and tries to access the uncalculated filePaths.